# Set style for custom compound component

Tags: android

After a long time of searching how to create custom compound component in android, I got the following in code:

```
public class MyCustomView extends RelativeLayout {
    ...
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, this, true);
}
```

To avoid double RelativeLayout, I have to use merge in my_custom_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    ...
</merge>
```

But I cannot specify style in the merge tag, how can I set style for MyCustomView using styles defined in styles.xml? This requirement seems quite common, but I cannot figure out an answer even after spending a long time over the web. Hope some experienced android developer could help me out. Thx~

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should be able to set the desired style in the constructor of your class:

```
super(context,attrs,R.style.MyCustomView);
```

But I can't get this to work neither because of a bug in the Android-platform. You can check the status of this bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12683).